# nix shell did not work in plutus-apps

Tags: plutus, nix

I checkout to branch **c2b310968d0915e2af0ea4680186b41ad88ffbe9** and run nix-shell at plutus-apps. No error, nothing change when I run nix-shell.I reinstalled nix, changed iohk-cache, reinstalled ubuntu. I still can't run nix-shell. Maybe that's my PC's wrong but I don't know. I need any help.

```
➜  plutus-apps git:(c2b310968) nix-shell
trace: To make project.plan-nix for haskell-project a fixed-output derivation but not materialized, set `plan-sha256` to the output of the 'calculateMaterializedSha' script in 'passthru'.
trace: To materialize project.plan-nix for haskell-project entirely, pass a writable path as the `materialized` argument and run the 'updateMaterialized' script in 'passthru'.
trace: To make project.plan-nix for cabal-install a fixed-output derivation but not materialized, set `plan-sha256` to the output of the 'calculateMaterializedSha' script in 'passthru'.
trace: To materialize project.plan-nix for cabal-install entirely, pass a writable path as the `materialized` argument and run the 'updateMaterialized' script in 'passthru'.
trace: To make project.plan-nix for cardano-node a fixed-output derivation but not materialized, set `plan-sha256` to the output of the 'calculateMaterializedSha' script in 'passthru'.
trace: To materialize project.plan-nix for cardano-node entirely, pass a writable path as the `materialized` argument and run the 'updateMaterialized' script in 'passthru'.
trace: To make project.plan-nix for haskell-project a fixed-output derivation but not materialized, set `plan-sha256` to the output of the 'calculateMaterializedSha' script in 'passthru'.
trace: To materialize project.plan-nix for haskell-project entirely, pass a writable path as the `materialized` argument and run the 'updateMaterialized' script in 'passthru'.
trace: To make project.plan-nix for haskell-project a fixed-output derivation but not materialized, set `plan-sha256` to the output of the 'calculateMaterializedSha' script in 'passthru'.
trace: To materialize project.plan-nix for haskell-project entirely, pass a writable path as the `materialized` argument and run the 'updateMaterialized' script in 'passthru'.
trace: To make project.plan-nix for haskell-project a fixed-output derivation but not materialized, set `plan-sha256` to the output of the 'calculateMaterializedSha' script in 'passthru'.
trace: To materialize project.plan-nix for haskell-project entirely, pass a writable path as the `materialized` argument and run the 'updateMaterialized' script in 'passthru'.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `nix-shell` is running, just give it time until it return the command line prompt again.

Comment: Yes, It's already done but nothing change. I thought its theme is wrong so I tried to build my project but It can not run.

Answer (score 0):

You should try nix develop. If you are using a new version of Nix.

Comment: Please add a bit more details to this answer. What is `nix develop` and how does it help to solve the problem?